# Change background of fullscreen keyboard TVOS app

Tags: objective-c, tvos, tvos10, tvos9.1

I am working on TVOS app using Objective C code and storyboard. I want to change background color of full-screen keyboard to black but default color is light gray. Would it be possible to change the color of the full-screen keyboard?
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customize Keyboard in tvOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33776421/customize-keyboard-in-tvos)

Comment: Thanks @the4kman. UIKeyboardAppearanceDark worked fine

Answer (score 2):

Use UIKeyboardAppearanceDark to make TVOS keyboard screen color dark.